# Why is the vue <template> invalid with v-bind:src?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I want to dynamically switch html content, so I used vue-loader src to import, but v-bind:src doesn't take effect at all.

```
<template src="./app.html"></template>
```

Ok,effective

```
<template :src="getDOM(true)"></template>

getDOM(a){
        if(a){
            return './app.html'
        } else {
            return './app2.html'
        }
}
```

Not active.

So, what can I do to achieve this effect?

Comment: Think of the `<template>` tag in single-file-components as the `template` string property or `render()` function of a component. It is just the wrapper and Vue directives are not executed on it but on its contents

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically switch html templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to use Vue dynamic components
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

You can make a couple of components with the different templates that you need and just change the `is` property. Don't forget to import the needed components and register them.

Comment: Dynamic components do work, but this is a transformation project. Changing the html of all pages into components is a huge task, so I am looking for something like` <template src="./app.html"></ Template>`
This method.

Comment: You can probably make a script to convert the HTML files to Vue files or make a component that loads the indicated file and puts the content in the template using `v-html`

Comment: But v-html won't be converted as a vue template, so`{{data}}, @click, <someTag>`
Will not be converted

Comment: You can't have both things, you need to register those as vue components or you won't get the vue functionality in a template